# Chunk loading with farms

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I have a spawner at y level 12 and AFK there will it run my farms at the the same x and z level above ground (will it load the chunks?)

Comment: The question isn't the same, but the answer is the same.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your farms above ground will also be loaded.

A [chunk](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk) is 256 blocks tall, so even if you are standing at y=12, areas at higher y-levels (but at the same x and z coordinates) will also be loaded.